# Get Image resolution from an URL in the background thread

Tags: swift, multithreading

I'm trying to get the resolution of an image from URL without actually downloading it. So I have a function for that:

```
public func resolutionForImage(url: String) -> CGSize? {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return  nil }
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let propertiesOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, propertiesOptions) as? [CFString: Any] else {
        return nil
    }
    
    if let width = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as? CGFloat,
       let height = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as? CGFloat {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I need to run it in the Background thread, in the main thread in block the UI

And this function is called in an another function in a collectionView cell, so in the end `calculateImageHeight` output should be in the main thread, could anyone help me manage it, still not in good in the threading

```
    public func calculateImageHeight(ratio: Double = 0.0) -> CGFloat {
        var calculatedRatio = ratio
        if ratio == 0.0 {
            if let size = resolutionForImage(url: imageUrl) {
                calculatedRatio = size.height/size.width
            }
        }
        let height = imageViewWidth * calculatedRatio
        return height.isFinite ? height : 100
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to use DispatchQueue or `async/await`?

Comment: I might be mistaken but I feel like this is still just downloading the full image data.

Comment: Yes as long as it doesn't effect in performance (BTW, I updated the first post, I didn't copy the full of the first function first by mistake)

Comment: "Yes" is not an answer to my question. "x or y" means "say x, or say y". I am asking you to _choose_ something.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, as long as it works on the background thread, it seems ok to me

Comment: Sorry @matt, I think of using DispatchQueue, but if async/await performance better is also fine to me. I need it to run as fast as possible without blocking UI

Comment: You can’t get the image size without downloading it unless you store it in your server.

Comment: I can’t provide a full answer but something like this is what you’re looking for. https://forums.swift.org/t/calling-synchronous-function-with-async-let/59211/4 Essentially you create a `Task` which runs asynchronously and inside it so your synchronous woke. Then you can await the task.

Comment: It's not a matter of speed. It's a matter of syntax (and, to some extent, backwards compatibility). If your app is iOS 15/16 only I would definitely recommend `async/await`. For one thing, the syntax is trivial to use and understand. Try it! This is a very easy thing to do.